# WP_User_Query takes time on huge database for pagination

Tags: database, wordpress

I have an issue with huge WordPress database to find users. I have about 147000 user into my database and 75000 users have same category. When i try to search users by a category for example "Doctors" then Query fails and page got stuck

I need $total_users from WP_User_Query to make pagination but it seems that query fail.

I also tried this [WP_User_Query unable to retrieve all user at once](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281251/wp-user-query-unable-to-retreive-all-user-at-once/281252)

but page load time is still too much.

```
$query_args = array(
                'role'  => 'professional',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'orderby' => 'ID',
             );
```

Can anyone there to help me to get this resolve?

here is the link : [Site link](http://web.sadoctorsapp.co.za/dir-search/by_name&city&directory_type=doctor&view&sort_by&order=ASC&per_page)

Thanks